# Android studio - error: cannot find symbol variable item

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm confused as to why 'item' is red and I am getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where is `item` declared? I can only see `menuItem`.

Comment: It is menuItem not item.

Comment: Change it to `menuItem` instead of `item` and delete this question. It is low quality.

Comment: @Xenolion Okay, cheers. Apologies

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have not declared `item` and it has no value. Try:

```
UserMenuSelector(menuItem);
```